# Delete columns based on average

Tags: r, matrix, filter, mean

I have this matrix:

```
row c1  c2  c3  c4  c5
R1  27  38  94  40  4
R2  69  16  85  2   15
R3  30  35  64  95  6
R4  20  33  77  98  55
R5  20  44  60  33  89
R6  12  88  87  44  38
```

I want to delete all columns in the matrix that have an average of less than 30. How is this done with `colMeans`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `colMeans` (assuming the `row` is the `row.names` of the `matrix`)

```
m1[, colMeans(m1, na.rm = TRUE) >= 30, drop = FALSE]
```

-output

```
   c2 c3 c4 c5
R1 38 94 40  4
R2 16 85  2 15
R3 35 64 95  6
R4 33 77 98 55
R5 44 60 33 89
R6 88 87 44 38
```

if `row` is a column, then it is not making sense as a `matrix` because a `matrix` can have only a single type and thus any character element changes the whole matrix to `character`.  Probably a `data.frame` would be better i.e.

```
df1[, c(TRUE, colMeans(df1[-1], na.rm = TRUE) >= 30), drop = FALSE]
```

-output

```
 row c2 c3 c4 c5
1  R1 38 94 40  4
2  R2 16 85  2 15
3  R3 35 64 95  6
4  R4 33 77 98 55
5  R5 44 60 33 89
6  R6 88 87 44 38
```

#### data

```
m1 <- structure(c(27L, 69L, 30L, 20L, 20L, 12L, 38L, 16L, 35L, 33L, 
44L, 88L, 94L, 85L, 64L, 77L, 60L, 87L, 40L, 2L, 95L, 98L, 33L, 
44L, 4L, 15L, 6L, 55L, 89L, 38L), .Dim = 6:5, .Dimnames = list(
    c("R1", "R2", "R3", "R4", "R5", "R6"), c("c1", "c2", "c3", 
    "c4", "c5")))

df1 <- structure(list(row = c("R1", "R2", "R3", "R4", "R5", "R6"), c1 = c(27L, 
69L, 30L, 20L, 20L, 12L), c2 = c(38L, 16L, 35L, 33L, 44L, 88L
), c3 = c(94L, 85L, 64L, 77L, 60L, 87L), c4 = c(40L, 2L, 95L, 
98L, 33L, 44L), c5 = c(4L, 15L, 6L, 55L, 89L, 38L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Answer (score 3):

If we change matrix to dataframe we could use `select` with condition: (data borrowed from akrun)

```
df1 %>% 
    select(which(colMeans(.) >= 30))
```

output:

```
   c2 c3 c4 c5
R1 38 94 40  4
R2 16 85  2 15
R3 35 64 95  6
R4 33 77 98 55
R5 44 60 33 89
R6 88 87 44 38
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option (but not as efficient as [@akrun's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68695835/12158757))

```
> as.matrix(Filter(function(x) mean(x) >= 30, data.frame(m)))
   c2 c3 c4 c5
R1 38 94 40  4
R2 16 85  2 15
R3 35 64 95  6
R4 33 77 98 55
R5 44 60 33 89
R6 88 87 44 38
```

Answer (score 2):

Another one, probably not very efficient:

```r
m1[, t(m1) %*% rep(1, dim(m1)[1])/dim(m1)[1] >= 30]

#>    c2 c3 c4 c5
#> R1 38 94 40  4
#> R2 16 85  2 15
#> R3 35 64 95  6
#> R4 33 77 98 55
#> R5 44 60 33 89
#> R6 88 87 44 38
```